# Swift Deeplink to already open App's already open viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, deeplink

I have an app that accepts a Deeplink URL and opens a viewcontroller with variables from the link and it works well if the App is opened/run for the first time by the user using the Deeplink.

However, if the App is already open/or in the background and has that view controller open... it then opens the same viewcontroller back up again so then I have two.  I do not want to open the viewcontroller an additional time.

Is there some way I can identify that viewcontroller that is already open and pass the variables from the Deeplink to it?

or do I need to close it in some way and re-open it?

I am open to suggestions.... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` and testing what class it is. For example:

```
if let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    if vc is SomeViewController {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the visible view controller with the following method

```
func getVisibleViewController(_ rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {

    var rootVC = rootViewController
    if rootVC == nil {
        rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    }

    if rootVC?.presentedViewController == nil {
        return rootVC
    }

    if let presented = rootVC?.presentedViewController {
        if presented.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self) {
            let navigationController = presented as! UINavigationController
            return navigationController.viewControllers.last!
        }

        if presented.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self) {
            let tabBarController = presented as! UITabBarController
            return tabBarController.selectedViewController!
        }

        return getVisibleViewController(presented)
    }
    return nil
}
```

you can then switch on the presented view

```
if let presentedView = getVisibleViewController(window?.rootViewController)  {
                        switch presentedView {
//code
default: 
//code
}
}
```

and of course in the switch present a view controller if it is not the one that you want to be open.

No need to close a viewcontroller before opening it!